# How to add an enum in class in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I define a model class and I would like to add an enum label like:

```
export class User {
    userID: number;
    nom: string;
    prenom: string;
    dateCretation: Date;
    statut: enum {
        Value1,
        Value2
    };
}
```

I got a mark error in enum:

> [ts] Type expected.

How can I resolve it ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You will need to declare the `enum` beforehand, and then type it to the properties that you want to have of that type:

```
export enum Values {
  Value1,
  Value2
}

export class User {
  userID: number;
  nom: string;
  prenom: string;
  dateCretation: Date;
  statut: Values
}
```

Another alternative is that if you know for sure that `statut` can only strictly take in two values, of which they are type of, say, `string`, then you can do like the following:

```
export class User {
  userID: number;
  nom: string;
  prenom: string;
  dateCretation: Date;
  statut: "Value1" | "Value2"
}
```

Answer (score 8):

What ever you are trying to do is not possible in TypeScript. As per my understanding, you need a data member of type Status enum. You can update your code this way

```
enum Status {
    Value1,
    Value2
};

export class User {
    userID: number;
    nom: string;
    prenom: string;
    dateCretation: Date;
    status: Status; // can hold either Value1 or Value2 from Status enum
}
```